# How to create a custom "add to cart" button in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning
I am trying to create a custom add to cart button that only works when the customer answers a question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ( /* Your condition ... */  ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
    function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
        return __( 'Your text...', 'woocommerce' ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want it to appear when they answer question correctly